# HttpWebResponse-The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, tableau-api

I am getting this error at "request.GetResponse()" trying to resolve this error but no luck.

My code is below:

```
    string workbookPath = HttpContext.Current.Session["WorkBookPath"].ToString();
        string wbName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(workbookPath);
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(workbookPath);
        byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(workbookPath);
        var boundary = "xxxxxxxPOSTxxBOUNDARY";
        System.IO.MemoryStream content = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(content);

        writer.WriteLine("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");
        writer.WriteLine("Content-Disposition: name=\"{0}\";"
                                 + "\r\nContent-Type: {1}\r\n\r\n",
                                 "request_payload",
                                 "text/xml");

        writer.WriteLine();

        var xml = @"<tsRequest><workbook name=""" + wbName + "\" project id=\"Test" + projectId + "\" /></tsRequest>";
        writer.WriteLine(xml);

        // Include the file in the post data
        writer.WriteLine("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");
        writer.WriteLine("Content-Disposition: name=\"{0}\";"
                                + "filename=\"{1}\""
                                + "\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n",
                                "tableau_workbook",
                                fileName,
                                "application/octet-stream");

        writer.Flush();

        // Read the file
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(workbookPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fileContents.Length];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            content.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        fileStream.Close();

        writer.WriteLine("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
        writer.Flush();

        HttpWebRequest oRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8000/api/2.0/sites/" + siteId + "/workbooks?overwrite=false");

        oRequest.Method = "POST";
        oRequest.Headers["X-Tableau-Auth"] = HttpContext.Current.Session["authToken"].ToString();

        using (var oStream = oRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            content.CopyTo(oStream);
            content.Close();
        }

        using (var oResponse = (HttpWebResponse)oRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var streamRdr = new StreamReader(oResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var response2 = streamRdr.ReadToEnd();
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(response2);

                oResponse.Close();
            }
        }
```

I am using Tableau Server to connect remotely on another PC. A lot of questions are raised with the same issue but none of them resolves my error.

The Stack Trace of the error is:

```
[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +6518932
   DashBoard.AddWorkBookToTabProject(String projectId, String siteId)      in c:\Project\DashBoard.aspx.cs:876
   RunRoutines.publishWorkbook() in c:\Project\RunRoutines.aspx.cs:76
   RunRoutines.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Project\RunRoutines.aspx.cs:55
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.<LoadRecursiveAsync>d__4.MoveNext() +228
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Web.Util.WithinCancellableCallbackTaskAwaiter.GetResult() +30
   System.Web.UI.<ProcessRequestMainAsync>d__14.MoveNext() +4346
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and did a lot of research. I believe this is a issue with your JSON rest request string. What you need to do is make sure that all special characters are properly escaped with double slashes. Example instead of \n make sure you have \ \n or instead of \t, \ \t etc. This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the error is probably in the special characters. I have updated the code with stack trace, can you help me figure out where exactly i am doing wrong formatting.